# Commuting morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If I have a diagram of morphism of schemes which commutes at level of global section, does the diagram commute?

Diagram commutes at level of topological spaces.

Comment: Is it an assumption that it commutes at the level of topological spaces, or are you asking whether you can conclude that it commutes at the level of topological spaces?

Comment: It is an assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems this problem is equivalent to asking if $f,f':X\to Y$ are two morphisms of schemes which are equal at the levels of topological spaces and global sections, if we can conclude $f=f'$. At least any such example leads to a counterexample to your question via the diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{f} >> Y\\
@VV{\mathrm{id}}V @VV\mathrm{id}V\\
X @>{f'} >> Y
\end{CD}

You can get a counterexample as follows: recall if $A$ is a ring of characteristic $p$ then the Frobenius morphism $a\mapsto a^p$ is a ring homomorphism $A\to A$ which induces the identity on the underlying topological space of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. By a gluing argument you can conclude that any scheme $X/\Bbb F_p$ has a "Frobenius" endomorphism $F:X\to X$ which is the identity at the level of topological spaces and has map on global sections given by $f\mapsto f^p$.

Now for the counterexample take $X=Y=\Bbb P^1_{\Bbb F_p}$, i.e. the projective line over $\Bbb F_p$. It is a standard fact that $\Gamma(\Bbb P^1_k)=k$ for any field $k$. Thus $\Gamma(X)=\Bbb F_p$, and it follows that the Frobenius endomorphism for $X$ is the identity on global sections. And it is also the identity at the level of topological spaces, but it is not the identity morphism.

Comment: How is your Frobenius endomorphism for your choice of X identity on global section?

Comment: @user474986 Because the global sections of $X$ are $\Bbb F_p$, and the map on global sections is $f\mapsto f^p$, which is the identity on $\Bbb F_p$ since $x^p=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: Yes right, thanks looks good.

Comment: I believe the global sections are in general $k[x,y]$ and not $k$ for the punctured plane? So instead you might want to take the projective space.

Comment: @Notone should be correct now.

Comment: @user474986 I made a mistake in my original answer; I said the global sections of the punctured plane were $k$ when they are actually $k[x,y]$. The only thing that was important was having a scheme $X$ over $\Bbb F_p$ whose global sections are exactly $\Bbb F_p$, so I have replaced the punctured plane with projective space in my answer and it should be correct now.